# ICollection from ViewModel showing up as null, modelstate is not valid in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following viewModel:

```
public class CreateCardViewModel
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int SetId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ICollection<Side> Sides { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsReady { get; set; }

    }
```

And the following actions defined for Create:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(int setId)
        {
            var model = new CreateCardViewModel();

            // attach card to current set
            model.SetId = setId;

            // create a new Side
            var side = new Side() {Content = "Blank Side"};

            // Add this to the model's Collection
            model.Sides = new Collection<Side> { side };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateCardViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var set = _db.Sets.Single(s => s.SetId == viewModel.SetId);
                var card = new Card {Sides = viewModel.Sides};

                set.Cards.Add(card);

                _db.Save();
            }
            return View(viewModel);


        }
```

When I try to create a new card, the Sides property of the viewModel is null, so the ModelState is coming up as null.  I can't quite figure out why that initial Side isn't getting passed with the model.

My View looks like this:

```
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CreateCardViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SetId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SetId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SetId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsReady)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsReady)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsReady)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: What's your view look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your View that is bound to the `Sides` property of your ViewModel. Without anything in the form to hold the value of that property, it will be null when model binding occurs. You'll need to somehow capture the `Side` in your form - how are you adding to/removing from this property? Via user interaction that should take place on the form?

Comment: Thanks for that - I didn't know every property of the viewmodel needs to be bound from the view.  Is that why the SetId needs to be there, but not displayed?  Without that, the card wouldn't be associated to a Set?

Comment: Seems like having that in the view is a little messy.  Is there a better way to take care of foreign keys?

Comment: Your ViewModel doesn't need to follow the same domain associations as your underlying model objects. You can, and I tend to, flatten the object and simply hold all the properties that the ViewModel needs to display and manipulate, Then, when you're actually mapping it back to the domain you can repopulate the domain object graph. If the property that you're mapping is a foreign key, you can store it in a `Html.Hidden` to ensure that it's passed back to the controller during model binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a second argument on Create() of type `ICollection<Side>` and see if that gets anything passed to it.

Comment: Just tried that - it's not getting anything there.  It seems like the view is accepting the viewmodel but it's not passing the sides from that viewmodel back into the controller.

Comment: Can you post a version of the HTML that the client sees prior to it being posted back?